# When I set the YScale to log, why do my XTickLabels disappear in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

When I set the `YScale` to `log`, why do my `xticklabels` disappear?

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
y = [0 1000 400 1 0 80000 500 100 1 200];
my_labels = [{'these', 'are', 'my', 'labels', 'to', 'use', 'for', 'my', 'cool', 'plot'}];
h2 = scatter(x,y,50,'b','o');
Xt = 1:1:10;
Xl = [1 10];
set(gca,'XTick',Xt,'XLim',Xl);
ax = axis;    
axis(axis);    
Yl = ax(3:4);  
delta=1000;
t = text(Xt,Yl(1)*ones(1,length(Xt))-delta,my_labels(1:1:10));
set(t,'HorizontalAlignment','right','VerticalAlignment','top', ...
          'Rotation',45,'fontsize',6);
set(gca,'XTickLabel','')
box on
set(gca,'YScale','log')
```

Comment: How did you define `x`, `y`, and `your_labels`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you did this:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel','')
```

This statement appears in the third-last line of the code you showed us.  You are causing your x-tick labels to disappear because you're clearing all of them by this statement.  It so happens that all your labels are being removed after you set your `YScale` to `log` because you are clearing your x-tick labels before that statement happens :)

Remove that statement and try your code again.

## Edit

The reason why it isn't working is because when you go to `log` scale, the `y` limits **cannot be negative**.  This is a `semilog` plot, which means that the **smallest** value of your `y` axis must be positive.  As such, you need to modify your code so that the text values are placed with a `y` value of at least `1` instead of a negative number.  This is as close as you're going to get without going off of the screen.  As such, you need to do this:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
y = [0 1000 400 1 0 80000 500 100 1 200];
my_labels = {'these', 'are', 'my', 'labels', 'to', 'use', 'for', 'my', 'cool', 'plot'};
h2 = scatter(x,y,50,'b','o');
Xt = 1:1:10;
Xl = [1 10];
set(gca,'XTick',Xt,'XLim',Xl);
%//ax = axis;    %// Remove because not possible
%//axis(axis);    
%//Yl = ax(3:4);  
%//delta=1000;
t = text(Xt,ones(1,length(Xt)),my_labels(1:1:10)); %// Change here
set(gca,'XTickLabel','') %// Move here
set(t,'HorizontalAlignment','right','VerticalAlignment','top', ...
          'Rotation',45,'fontsize',6);
box on
set(gca,'YScale','log')
```

---

This is the plot I get:
[image]

---

In general, if you want this method to work, you should set the `y` values for the text values so that it's the minimum of the **log** of the y values **then add 1** in case any of your `y` values are zero.  This is because when you do a `log` scale for the `y` values, all of these values get a `log10` operation applied to them.  In other words, change your `text` statement to this:

```
t = text(Xt,min(log10(y + 1))*ones(1,length(Xt)),my_labels(1:1:10));
```

This should work regardless of your `y` values.  However, because you're doing a `log` plot, you need to make sure that your `y` values are `> 0`.

Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for your reply but this doesn't work for me - if I remove that line then I lose my text labels and just get numbers as xticklabels instead...

Comment: @user2861089 - the reason why is because when you are doing the `log` scale, it messes up the syntax where you are placing your `text` in your axis.  I'll need to play around with this to get it right.

Comment: @rayryeng Found this work - `
delta=10;
set(gca,'XTickLabel','')
set(gca,'YScale','log')
t = text(Xt,log10(Yl(1)*ones(1,length(Xt))+delta),my_labels(1:1:10));
set(t,'HorizontalAlignment','right','VerticalAlignment','top', ...
          'Rotation',45,'fontsize',6);
box on`

Comment: Also I suggest changing `Yl(1)` to `min(Yl)`. `delta` can be something  from 6 to 12.

Comment: @Yvon - Nice.  I removed that placement of the text axis because of the log scale.  Instead of playing around with the delta, I forced it to go to `y = 1`.  Nice!

Comment: Both your method and mine failed when `min(y)>10`

Comment: @Yvon - Try my method where you eliminate the `delta`.  I've just placed a new edit.  Look at the bottom of the post.

Comment: With your last edit (I hope I'm using the correct version), when `0 < min(y) < 10` the ticks are inside the plot.

Comment: Thank! This works for `me t = text(Xt,(min(y) + 1)*ones(1,length(Xt))-delta,my_labels(1:1:10));`

Comment: @user2861089 In case `min(y)>0` you can replace `(min(y)+1)` with `delta` and `delta = (min(y)==0)*1+min(y);`. That includes both cases.